# Vim omnicppcomplete 'using namespace' issue

Tags: c++, vim, autocomplete

I apologise if this question has been asked before, I had a quick look but I had trouble finding specific enough search terms.

I have gvim working with omnicppcomplete according to [this guide](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/C++_code_completion)

It works correctly when I begin to type

```
std::
```

completing for members of the namespace

It also works when I do

```
std::string a;
a.
```

completing for the String class

When I do this however, it gives me a pattern not found error

```
using namespace std;
String a;
a.
```

If you know any way to get around this problem, I would be grateful for your help

Comment: `String` should be `string` (but no idea if that fixes your issue).

Comment: Wow, I really need some sleep. That was so stupid. Post that as an answer and I'll accept it. Probably also affected by java experience and the whole string isnt a primitive type thing

Comment: Unrelated: in the edit queue, I came across a question that you voted on in triage. You made the wrong choice there. Please: study the help for triage really carefully, and avoid putting items into the edit queue that don't belong there. Please understand that your votes have consequences! I am specifically talking about https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/20896605. That request is way too broad, and such be closed as such. No other person but the OP would be able to "fix" the question via editing, therefore editing is absolutely wrong here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`String` should be `string`. C++ is case-sensitive.